# Changing a Collection from within a loop

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a simple `Dictionary(of String, Object)` that I need to iterate through and change items depending on some conditions.

As I can't modify a collection that I'm iterating through, how do I achieve this?

For example, the following obviously causes an `Invalid Operation Exception`:

```
Dim mOptions As New Dictionary(of String, Object)
mOptions.Add("optA", "A")
mOptions.Add("optB", "B")
mOptions.Add("optC", "C")

For Each O As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In mOptions
    Dim Val As Object = GetSomeOtherObjectBasedOnTheOption(O.Key, O.Value)
    mOptions(O.Key) = Val
Next
```

**Invalid Operation Exception**
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

I guess I need to Clone the Dictionary first and iterate over the copy?  What's the best way of doing that?

```
Dim TempOptions As New Dictionary(of String, Object)
For Each O As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In mOptions
    TempOptions.Add(O.Key, O.Value)
Next

For Each O As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In TempOptions
    Dim Val As Object = GetSomeOtherObjectBasedOnTheOption(O.Key, O.Value)
    mOptions(O.Key) = Val
Next
```

That smells a bit though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just iterate over *a copy of* the keys instead of iterating over the `KeyValuePair`s.

```
For Each K as String in mOptions.Keys.ToArray()
   Dim Val As Object = GetSomeOtherObjectBasedOnTheOption(K)
   mOptions(K) = Val
Next
```

(sorry if you can't just paste that in -- I don't normally write VB)

It doesn't strictly have to be an array: you can do the VB equivalent of `foreach (string k in new List<string>(mOptions.Keys))` as well, for instance.

If you iterate over the original keys and modify your dictionary, you'll get the same error.

Comment: I think I was doing this the wrong way around.  I need the keys _and_ the values, not just the keys, but your approach works fine - I just get the current val from the original collection at the top of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why iterate over KeyValuePairs?

Why not do this?

```
For Each K As String In mOptions.Keys.ToArray()
  Dim Val As Object = GetSomeOtherObjectBasedOnTheOption(K)
  mOptions(K) = Val
Next
```

This way, the collection your iterating over is a list of strings which can be used to access the Dictionary, not the Dictionary itself.

*Apologies in advance for any crap VB.  Haven't done it in years*

Answer (score -2):

in C# this can be done by using the yield pattern, don't know if it's also possible in VB.NET, otherwise you could create a custom IEnumerable that allows it...

Comment: Negative vote from me because this answer is phrased in a potentially misleading way, and focuses on C# instead of on a working VB.NET solution. The meaning would have been clearer if you had said it the other way around: _"This can be done by implementing a custom `IEnumerable`. Use `yield` for that purpose (if it is available in VB.NET)."_ (`yield` is not available in VB.NET btw., at least not in VS 2008.) -- However that may be, I think writing a custom iterator would be overkill, and therefore a bad idea. There's easier solutions.